# How to execute custom delegate methods like UITableViewDataSource in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I have a `UIButton` in one `UIViewController`. I am print the text by using custom delegate. Now, the problem is delegate method not execute at ideal when `viewDidAppear(animated)`.(i.e., like `UITableViewDataSource`)

**Protocol:**

```
protocol FruitDelegate{

    func fruit(_ name:String,taste:String)->Bool
}
```

**Fruit Class**

```
class Fruit{

    var delegate:FruitDelegate?

    var name:String!
    var taste:String!

    init(name:String,taste:String){
        self.name = name
        self.taste = taste

    }

    func isTrue(){

        if self.delegate?.fruit(name, taste: taste) == true{

            print("Answer Correct")
        }else{

            print("Answer Wrong")
        }
    }

}
```

**View Controller:**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,FruitDelegate {


    @IBOutlet var textLabel: UILabel!

    let fruit = Fruit(name: "mango", taste: "sweet")


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.fruit.delegate = self
    }

    func fruit(_ name: String, taste: String) -> Bool {

        if name == "mango" && taste == "sweet"{

            return true
        }else{
            return false
        }
    }


    @IBAction func actionRefreshButton(_ sender: UIButton) {

        self.fruit.isTrue()
    }


}
```

I know below code will give me the exact solution for my problem.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.fruit.delegate = self
    self.fruit.isTrue()
}
```

But, Is it necessary to call `self.fruit.isTrue()` on `viewController` methods? (upto `viewDidAppear`). In `UITableView` there is no need to call `reloadData()` at ideal when view is appear. Same way, I need to  execute `FruitDelegate` method. How to I do?

Comment: use a didSet for delegate variable in your Fruit class maybe?

Comment: @koropok, Thanks bro I will try it and let you know

Comment: @koropok , You are correct. Thank you very much bro.

Comment: you're welcome :D

Comment: Unrelated, you have a strong reference cycle here. ViewController has strong reference to `Fruit` and `Fruit` has strong reference to its `delegate`, the view controller. You make break this strong reference cycle if you make your protocol a "class protocol" (e.g. `protocol FruitDelegate: class { ... }`) and then make your `delegate` property a weak property.

Comment: @Rob, Okay Thank you so much :) I will keep it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to call `isTrue` method in your `didSet` of your delegate var

```
class Fruit{

    var delegate:FruitDelegate{
       didSet{
          self.isTrue()
       }
    }

    var name:String!
    var taste:String!

    init(name:String,taste:String){
        self.name = name
        self.taste = taste

    }

    func isTrue(){

        if self.delegate?.fruit(name, taste: taste) == true{

            print("Answer Correct")
        }else{

            print("Answer Wrong")
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Exact answer :) Thanks bro :)